Returning wchar_t* from C++ DLL function to C# not working
I'm maintaining some old C++ code, and I've been struggling all day trying to figure out why this code doesn't work when calling it from C#. The first function works fine, the second fails.
C/C++ DLL code:

#define EXPFUNC extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

static const wchar_t *TEST = const_cast<wchar_t*> (L"TEST");

EXPFUNC const unsigned int __stdcall testFunc1(const wchar_t *str) {

    // there is logic here that does a lookup using *str and returns an id

    return 123;
}

EXPFUNC const wchar_t* __stdcall testFunc2(const unsigned int id) {

    // there is logic here that does a lookup using id and returns the pointer

    return TEST;
}

C# code:
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern uint testFunc1([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string symbol);        

[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
internal static extern string testFunc2(uint id);


testFunc1("some string");  // works

testFunc2(123);  // exited with code 3221226356


Could be useful: decoder 3221226356.

There are two problems with your C# code:

You are declaring both DLL functions using CallingConvention.Cdecl, but both functions are exported using __stdcall rather than __cdecl, so you need CallingConvention.Stdcall instead.

Your C# code is marshaling the return value of testFunc2() as UnmanagedType.BStr:

A Unicode character string that is a length-prefixed double byte. You can use this member, which is the default string in COM, on the String data type.

However, in your C++ code, testFunc2() is NOT returning a valid BSTR. It is instead returning a pointer to a static const wchar_t[] array, which does not satisfy either the memory or layout requirements of a BSTR.



In C and C++, the BSTR type is declared as an alias for a wchar_t* pointer, but it is NOT a plain C-style wchar_t string, as you are treating it.  A BSTR is length-prefixed, meaning it holds its length at the beginning of its data. That value can be queried using the SysStringLen() function. Also, a BSTR must be allocated using the COM memory allocator, via either one of the SysAllocString...() functions or the CoTaskMemAlloc() function.
Just because a C/C++ compiler will treat wchar_t* and BSTR interchangeably DOES NOT mean they actually are.  NEVER use a wchar_t* where you expect a BSTR, and vice versa.  Be explicit so you can tell the difference between them, eg:
EXPFUNC const unsigned int __stdcall testFunc1(BSTR str);
EXPFUNC BSTR __stdcall testFunc2(const unsigned int id);

Now, that being said...
In testFunc1(), you are marshaling a native C# string as a BSTR and receiving it with a plain wchar_t* pointer.  This will work, because a BSTR can be read from as if it were a C-style null-terminated string.  However, BSTR marshaling is unnecessary overhead in this case, you can safely use UnmanagedType.LPWStr instead (unless you need to pass a Unicode string with embedded NUL characters in it, then BSTR makes more sense).
But, in testFunc2(), the C# marshaler will take ownership of the returned BSTR and free it using CoTaskMemFree() after converting its character data to a native C# string. But, in your case, it can't query the BSTR or free it, which is why it is crashing.
Try this instead:
static const wchar_t *TEST = L"TEST";

EXPFUNC const unsigned int __stdcall testFunc1(const wchar_t *str) {
    ...
    return 123;
}

EXPFUNC BSTR __stdcall testFunc2(const unsigned int id) {
    ...
    return SysAllocString(TEST);
}

[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
internal static extern uint testFunc1([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string symbol);        

[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
internal static extern string testFunc2(uint id);

testFunc1("some string");
testFunc2(123);

If you want to avoid using BSTR in testFunc2(), you might be tempted to marshal the return value as UnmanagedType.LPWStr instead of UnmanagedType.BStr, eg:
static const wchar_t *TEST = L"TEST";

EXPFUNC const wchar_t* __stdcall testFunc2(const unsigned int id) {
    ...
    return TEST;
}

[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
internal static extern string testFunc2(uint id);

testFunc2(123);

However, this will NOT work, because the C# marshaler will still try to free the returned memory and fail:
Default Marshalling Behavior

The interop marshaller always attempts to free memory allocated by unmanaged code. This behavior complies with COM memory management rules, but differs from the rules that govern native C++.
...
The runtime always uses the CoTaskMemFree method on Windows and free method on other platforms to free memory.

Since the returned memory is not being allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc(), this will not work.  Fortunately, the above documentation provides a solution:

If the memory you are working with was not allocated with the CoTaskMemAlloc method on Windows or malloc method on other platforms, you must use an IntPtr and free the memory manually using the appropriate method. Similarly, you can avoid automatic memory freeing in situations where memory should never be freed, such as when using the GetCommandLine function from Kernel32.dll, which returns a pointer to kernel memory.

This is exactly the same as your situation.  So, if you want the C++ code to maintain ownership of the string memory, you will have to make the C# code accept testFunc2()'s return value as an IntPtr, which you can marshal to a string using Marshal.PtrToStringUni(), eg:
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
internal static extern IntPtr testFunc2(uint id);

Marshal.PtrToStringUni(testFunc1(123));


Thanks but if I use return SysAllocString() won't the C++ side have to free it? This method is going to be called alot and I'm trying to avoid that. I already created all the pointers on the C++ side ... just want to share the pointers to C# without any need for new memory allocations. Although I could live with copying all the pointer values to the C# side and keeping them all in a list as a global variable so I only have to call the C++ dll once on startup... looks like your last example does just that? I just want to be safe from any memory leaks on the C++ dll side.

"if I use return SysAllocString() won't the C++ side have to free it?" - no, because as I stated in my answer, the C# marshaler will take ownership of the BSTR and free it. "I ... just want to share the pointers to C# without any need for new memory allocations" - then you shouldn't be using UnmanagedType.BStr.

I tried the MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr) example and I still get the same error.

" then you shouldn't be using UnmanagedType.BStr" ... so your last approach is best I assume? Marshal.PtrToStringUni(testFunc1(123))

@user1337497 I have updated my answer.

Perfect! As for my first function call where I pass the C++ dll a C# string marshalled as a BStr... should that be changed as well to something else?

@user1337497 I already covered that in my answer, please re-read it more carefully

Thanks for the help... it's working!

I was reviewing your comments again for more clarity and your very first comment where you say "you are declaring both DLL functions using CallingConvention.Cdecl, but both functions are exported using __stdcall rather than __cdecl" ... I updated my code example to show that I "#define EXPFUNC extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)". Not sure if this changes your comment or if it still applies?

@defa0009 No, that doesn't change what I said. The problem I describe still applies. Your DLL functions are declared with __stdcall separately from EXPFUNC, so you must use CallingConvention.Stdcall on the C# side. Calling conventions control how parameters are passed, and how the call stack is managed. Mismatching the calling convention will lead to bad things

Thanks for clearing that up. Appreciate it.
